# How can I make the EditText IME "Next" button not take to the next focusable EditText, if not completed correctly

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, ime

So far I have this layout:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/email_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/icn_email_settings"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/checked_icon_cont"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/checked_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_green_checked"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        <nl.hgrams.passenger.ui.EditTextBackEvent
            android:id="@+id/login_email_field"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/email_icon"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/checked_icon_cont"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:hint="mail@example.com"
            android:textSize="19dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="#cccccc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/pass_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/email_container"
            android:layout_height="44dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pass_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:src="@drawable/icn_password_settings"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/pass_icon"
                android:background="@color/gray_lighter"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/checked_icon_cont_pass"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/checked_icon_pass"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_green_checked"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <nl.hgrams.passenger.ui.EditTextBackEvent
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="18dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/checked_icon_cont_pass"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/pass_icon"
                android:ems="10"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="#cccccc"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:id="@+id/passwordEditField"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Password"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

And this code:

```
   TextView.OnEditorActionListener doneListener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                if (isEmailValid(emailField.getText().toString()) && validatePassword(passwordEditField.getText().toString())){
                    performEmailCheck();
                }else requestFocusDelayed(passwordEditField);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    EditTextImeBackListener listener = new EditTextImeBackListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImeBack(EditTextBackEvent ctrl, String text) {
            Log.i("", "closed keyboard");
            base.findViewById(R.id.container).performClick();
        }
    };
    emailField.setOnEditTextImeBackListener(listener);
    emailField.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                if (isEmailValid(emailField.getText().toString())){
                    requestFocusDelayed(passwordEditField);
                }else requestFocusDelayed(emailField);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    passwordEditField.setOnEditTextImeBackListener(listener);
    passwordEditField.setOnEditorActionListener(doneListener);

     public void requestFocusDelayed(final EditTextBackEvent view){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.requestFocus();
        }
    },10);
}
```

Now this works. but it is visible how the focus line goes from the first to the second EditText and then back to the first.
Without setting a 10ms delay, it goes from the first to the second EditText.
Desired effect: If valid, go to the secondary field. If not valid, remain on the first field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the `android:nextFocusForward="@id/sameObjectID"` to my EditTexts, so then when I would press the IME "Next" button, it would not change focus, and I would change it after that with my delayed method. Hence, if it is needed to change, it will change after 10ms, if not, it will remain on the same view (and change after 10ms to the same one), but like this, that jump from 1 EditText to another will not be visible anymore.
I feel like this is a hack, so I'm open to other suggestions